# Cross thread error reading form control

Tags: vb.net

I'm learning VB.NET coming from a VB6 and Java background.

In my app, I've got a function that validates the fields on a form.  All it is doing is reading them, not updating.  I've searched and see info about the backgroundWorker class, but all the examples are about updating the fields.

I understand the idea of threading and how it works, but have never written code that spawned threads myself.  I've always let the language handle it.  It seems like a lot of work that I would have to write a sub using the backgroundWorker for every time I wanted to read or update each field.  The couple of books I've got that introduce you to the language show you reading or updating the field directly.

How do I know what threads are running other than writing the code like I'm used to then running through debugger to figure out what variables are on which thread?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx) is some reading on the BackgroundWorkerProcess. My advice, don't use this unless you have to i.e. only when you have a long running process and want to

- Have the user switch between screens while that task is running.
- Use a progress indicator on the form

That being said, I find it useful in cases like processing invoices. When I have to generate say, 4k invoices, while that task is running I can put an indacator on the form.

I find the following book helpful "Visual Basic 2008 Recipes" in explaining several use of threading, including the BackGroundWorker

Comment: Thanks,  I'd rather not have to use it, but when debugging, I'm getting the cross thread error.  I'm not updating the UI while doing the validation.  I'm building a string to use in a messagebox if the validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

The background worker does a lot of work for you. Certainly easier than managing threads and marshalling callbacks yourself. However, I agree with Saif... no point in doing any work unless there is some benefit to be had. Use it only for processes that may potentially take a lot of time.

Hopefully you're using VS2010, as it added some threading features. For example, use the Debug Location toolbar to select the thread of interest.